# Sample polymer-enabled Chrome App not running

Tags: google-chrome, polymer, google-chrome-app, web-component, chrome-dev-editor

I just installed Chrome Dev Editor and gave it a try with one of the sample templates:

- New Project >> Project Type = JavaScript Chrome App (using Polymer paper elements) >> Create
- Right-click >> Refactor for CSP
- Click on Run (black arrow)

A window opens with what seems to be the sample Polymer app, without Polymer features (only html markup). Here is what the Console reports in Developer Tools:

```
extensions::platformApp:31 Uncaught Error: document.write() is not available in packaged apps.
index.html:338 GET chrome-extension://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoDraft:regular,bold,italic,thin,light,bolditalic,black,medium&lang=en net::ERR_FAILED
core-resizable.html.0.js:95 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
polymer.html.0.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined
unresolved.js:30 Uncaught ReferenceError: Platform is not defined
queue.js:138 Uncaught ReferenceError: CustomElements is not defined
```

I find it quite surprising that sample apps bundled with the IDE do not work out of the box, so I guess I must be doing something wrong somewhere...

My question is : does anyone know what changes i should make to the sample code or to my configuration to have it run properly?

Thanks

Note: might be useful, I'm using Chrome Version 39.0.2171.71 m

Comment: Yes, seems like the sample app is horribly broken with respect to Chrome Apps platform. What's your question though?

Comment: Well, i'd like to package my webapp as an android app, and thought Chrome Apps were just appropriate for this purpose...

Comment: This is _still_ not a question.

Comment: Ok, i thought the question marks at the end of two sentances in my post clearly demonstrated their interrogative nature. Edited the post to be cristal clear. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I only noticed your edit after I wrote that. Well, I think the answer is "looks unsalvageable". Have you looked at the issue tracker for CDE?

Comment: Specifically: https://github.com/dart-lang/chromedeveditor/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

To fix, just update your Chrome Dev Editor and make sure it's at version 0.18.3465 in the About dialog (to update, just relaunch the app the app: that should be sufficient). 0.18.3465 is a hot fix I've just pushed to the Chrome Web Store.

**Details**

The immediate problem was triggered by the bleeding edge Polymer sources that very recently broke compatibility with Chrome Apps in a few places.

On the other hand, Chrome Dev Editor 0.18 was supposed to pin down the Polymer version used in the templates to the latest stable release, denoted as `...#latest` in all Polymer package specifications inside the `bower.json` of a generated project. However, it contained a bug that sometimes (just after a fresh installation) generated `bower.json`'s pointing at the bleeding edge Polymer, denoted as `...#master`. So the above-mentioned hot fix was just fixing that bug.

Just to be sure, you could look in the `bower.json` of a newly generated project and see what's in there. If the problem persists, please file a bug at https://github.com/dart-lang/chromedeveditor/issues/new.

Comment: AB-SO-LU-TE-LY. Impressive. Thanks a lot!